# Allowing users to modify imported ES6 module functions in context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, es6-modules

I'm getting rather confused as to if something is possible or not.

I create a module that contains the following:

```
export function logText(){
    console.log('some text');
}

export class Example {
    constructor(){
        logText();
    }
}
```

The intent is for the user to call `new Example` to start off the module logic.

```
import { logText, Example } from 'example';

// Do some magic here to modify the functionality of logText

new Example();
```

**Is it possible for the end user to modify logText?**

It would make sense for there to be a way for users to do something like this, or they'd have to take the entire module into their own repo just to make small functionality tweaks.

I frequently see repos with lots of functions exported that are useless without the users having to remake almost all the functionality manually, making it rather pointless to do. One good example is [this repo](https://github.com/Pageclip/valid-form) whre theuy even call the exported functions their 'API'. In that example these are rather pointless exports and at worse would just cause issues if someone tried to use them in conjunction with the main function. But if you could modify them and have them still run then it would make sense to me.

Comment: What kind of modifications?

Comment: What's the difference between functions where "users having to remake almost all the functionality manually, making it rather pointless to do." and your idea of `Do some magic here to modify the functionality`?

Comment: @vlaz The difference between modifying one single exported function and rebuilding the entire module from scratch.

Comment: @FrankModica Any modifications, that's just the most bare bones example I could come up with. in that example, idk, i want to alert instead of console log. but in a real world example, it would depend on the function in question, maybe  just to be able to take a function and do the exact same stuff but then trigger an event.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that is different than @FelixKling's answer is to build "hooks" into your logger, like `onBeforeLog` or `onAfterLog`, or to have it provide options on what kind of logging to do. You don't really want to let people change your function drastically right? You probably want to define what they can change in some way.

Comment: You need to be a LOT more specific about what type of behavior you want to be customizable with detailed examples.  You can expose callbacks that the implementation uses for the user to supply their own custom behaviors (for example like `array.sort()` or `array.filter()` do.  You can accept options that allow the user to select one of several behaviors or to provide parameters that the built-in implementation will use or even to insert their own function to offer a custom behavior.  But, ALL of this is specific to exactly what customization you want the user to be able to apply.

Comment: @jfriend00 I literally can't be specific, that's the point of the issue. I see third party modules, i look at the code and I see exposed exported functions. I think to self, can they be modified, and have the logic for that module still work? No changed to the module at all, just, can i modify that one bit.

Comment: @ChrisMorris - I don't understand what you mean by "modify the exposed exported function".  Do you mean replace it with your own implementation?  Or do you mean to edit the module's code and then attempt to use the module?  Or what?

Comment: If you're not going to be more specific about what kind of modification, then this question is probably just "too broad" as there is no generic answer.  You can modify the code within the module and use the modified module and then you're on the hook for making modifications that preserve the other functionality.  Or, you can use the module as it was intended to be used.    Or, a module can be designed up front with certain customizability to it (callbacks, options, user-supplied objects, subclassing, etc...).  Those are pretty much your choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this:

```
import { logText, Example } from 'example';
```

> Is it possible for the end user to modify logText?

Since you aren't being very specific about what you mean by "modify logText", I'll go through several options:

> Can you reassign some other function to the variable `logText`?

No.  You cannot do that.  When you use `import`, it creates a variable that is `const` and cannot be assigned to.  Even if it wasn't const, it's just a local symbol that wouldn't affect the other module's use of its `logText()` anyway.  The `import` mechanism is designed this way on purpose.  A loader of your module is not supposed to be able to replace internal implementation pieces of the module that weren't specifically designed to be replaced.

> Can you modify the code inside of the `logText` function from outside of the module that contains it?

No, you cannot.  The code within modules lives inside it's own function scope which gives it privacy.  You cannot modify code within that module from outside the module.

> Can you replace the `logText()` function inside the module such that the implementation of `Example` inside that class will use your `logText()` function?

No, you cannot do that from outside the module.  You would have to actually modify the module's code itself or someone would have to design the Example interface to have a replaceable or modifiable `logText()` function that the Example object used.

For example, `logText()` could be made a method on Example and then you could override it with your own implementation which would cause Example's implementation to use your override.

Code in the module that you do not modify:

```
export class Example {
    constructor(){
        this.logText();
    }
    logText() {
        console.log('some text');
    }
}
```

Code doing the import:

```
import { Example } from 'example';

class MyExample extends Example {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    logText() {
        console.log("my own text");
    }
}

let o = new MyExample();
```

> Can you create your own version of `logText` and use it locally?

Sure, you can do that.

```
function myLogText() {
    do your own thing
}
```

And, you could even NOT import logText so that you could use the symbol name `logText()` locally if you wanted.  But, that won't affect what Example does at all.

> Are there ways to design the example module so that that `logText()` can be easily replaced.

Yes, there are lots of ways to do that.  I showed one above that makes `logText` a method that can be overriden.  It could also be passed as an optional argument to the `Example` constructor.

There could even be an exported object that allowed the caller to replace properties on that object.  For example:

```
export const api = {
    logText: function logText(){
        console.log('some text');
    }
};

export class Example {
    constructor(){
        api.logText();
    }
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
import { api, Example } from 'example';

api.logText = function() {
    console.log('my Text');
};
```

I would generally not recommend this because it sets you up for usage conflicts between multiple users of the same module where each one tries to modify it globally in ways that conflict with each other.  The subclassing model (mentioned above) lets each use of the module customize in its own way without conflicting with other usages of the module.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the end user to modify logText?

No, that's not possible, `import` bindings are immutable, and function objects are basically immutable wrt the code they contain.

> It would make sense for there to be a way for users to do something like this, or they'd have to take the entire module into their own repo just to make small functionality tweaks.

Why not make the log function an optional argument in the constructor? Usually when something is variable it becomes a parameter.

```
export class Example {
    constructor(log=logText){
        log();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `import`s are immutable, you can definitely import an `Object` and change its keys/values, right?

Comment: The sample function is way too basic to be of any use for actual solutions as in real uses it would be for critical logic. Why do I see so many modules exporting functions that wouldn't work anywhere else if you can't do anything else with them but remake the rest of the module?

Comment: @Cristy: I should have been more precise. The *bindings* are immutable. If the value is mutable, then of course it can be changed (just like how `const` work). Functions are essential immutable though wrt to their code.

Comment: @ChrisMorris: I can't speak to that, I would need to see an actual example. One reason could be tests.